# Mockito argument matcher with multiple arguments

Tags: java, mockito

I have a class with method:

```
class URAction {
      public List<URules> getUrules(Cond cond, Cat cat) {
             ...
      } 
}
```

I want to create its mock:

```
@Mock
URAction uraMock;

@Test
public void testSth() {
    Cond cond1;
    Cat cat1;
    List<URule> uRules;

    // pseudo code
    // when uraMock's getUrules is called with cond1 and cat1
    // then return uRules
}
```

The problem is I can make the mock return uRules for only one argument:

```
 when(uraMock.getUrules(argThat(
        new ArgumentMatcher<Cond> () {

            @Override
            public boolean matches(Object argument) {
                Cond cond = ((Cond) argument);
                 if (cond.getConditionKey().equals(cond1.getConditionKey()) 
                     return true;
                 return false;
            }

        }
    ))).thenReturn(uRules);
```

Not sure how to pass the second argument ie Cat in the when call above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: one solution would be to use `when(uraMock.getUrules(any(Cond.class), any(Cat.class).thenAnswer(new Answer() { })`, and check args in the implemented answer. see http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/stubbing/Answer.html

Comment: That seems to be a viable solution. How can I mark this as answer? It is only in the comment.

Comment: Let's do this: add an answer based on my comment and accept it, this could give you some rep. ;)

Comment: But this answer doesn't check if the parameter is the same as originally passed. It just checks for any object. The answer I've provided below validates that

Comment: @user1539343 just use: `when(uraMock.getUrules(cond1,cat1)).thenReturn(uRules);`
This is as simple as the one in the first comment and also checks the params passed

Comment: @Mindaugas, this will work only if the equality conditions meet for the Cond and Cat ie there are equals method that match the arguments.

Comment: @Gunith, please check the link RC provided.

Answer (score 4):

Could you try adding another argThat(argumentMatcher) for the second argument matcher?

Also, I find it's better to not have the anonymous class defined as a method and not inline as you have done. Then you could use it for verify() as well.

Your methods should look like this

```
ArgumentMatcher<Cond> matcherOne(Cond cond1){
   return new ArgumentMatcher<Cond> () {
        @Override
        public boolean matches(Object argument) {
            Cond cond = ((Cond) argument);
            if (cond.getConditionKey().equals(cond1.getConditionKey()) 
               return true;
            return false;
        }
   }
}

ArgumentMatcher<OtherParam> matcherTwo(OtherParam otherParam){
   return new ArgumentMatcher<OtherParam> () {
        @Override
        public boolean matches(Object argument) {
            OtherParam otherParam = ((OtherParam) argument);
            if (<some logic>) 
               return true;
            return false;
        }
   }
}
```

Then you could call your methods like this,

```
when(uraMock.getUrules(argThat(matcherOne(cond1)), argThat(matcherTwo(otherParam)))).thenReturn(uRules);
```

Then, as I you could call [verify](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html), to check if your when method really got called

```
verify(uraMock).getUrules(argThat(matcherOne(cond1)), argThat(matcherTwo(otherParam)));
```

If you don't care about the other param, you can do,

```
when(uraMock.getUrules(argThat(matcherOne(cond1)), argThat(any()))).thenReturn(uRules);
```

For more details see: http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/stubbing/Answer.html

Hope that's clear.. Good luck!